# Axiom 3. Comprehension Scheme

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, axioms

The following is from Kenneth Kunen's Book - *Set Theory, An Introduction to Independence Proofs.*

> The Comprehension Axiom is intended to formalize the construction of sets of the form $\{x:P(x)\}$ where $P(x)$ denotes some property of $x.$ Since the notion of property is made rigorous via formulas, it is tempting to set forth as axioms statements of the form
>
> $$ \exists y \forall x (x\in y \iff \phi)$$
> where $\phi$ is a formula. Unfortunately, such a scheme is inconsistent by the famous Russell paradox : If $\phi$ is $x\in x,$ then this axiom gives us a $y$ such that  $$ \forall x(x\in y \iff x\notin x),$$
> whence $y\in y \iff y\notin y.$ Fortunately in mathematical applications it is sufficient to be able to use a property $P(x)$ to define a subset of a given set, so we Postulate Comprehension as follows.
>
> Axiom 3. *Comprehension Scheme.* For each formula $\phi$ without $y$ free, the universal closure of the following is an axiom  $$\exists y \forall x(x\in y \iff x\in z \,\wedge \phi).$$

My Question : Why is it that Axiom $3$ can prevent Russel Paradox in comparison with the first proposed definition? Can we not argue that if $\phi$ is $x\notin x $ in Axiom $3$ and come up with Russel Paradox again? Why is the introduction of $z$ in Axiom $3$ helpful?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Right! Edited, Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we repeat the construction of Russell's Paradox with Axiom 3 above, what we get is:

> $\forall x (x \in y \Leftrightarrow x \in z \land x \notin x)$

and instantiating it with $y$: $(y \in y \Leftrightarrow y \in z \land y \notin y)$, for some $y$, which is not a contradiction.

Can you see why? The formula built-up from the axiom asserts that for a set $z$ whatever we can find a suitable $y$ that satisfies it. In general, it is enough that $z \notin z$: in this case, we can select $z$ itself as value for $y$ and the left and the right-hand sides are both false, thus satisfying the formula.

---

The Comprehension Axiom is "too liberal" because it asserts the existence of every set for which we can specify a condition (the formula $\phi$).

In Axiom 3 [the so-called [Specification axiom (schema)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification)] we have a crucial modification: the specifying formula $\phi$ must be applied to a preexisting set $z$: it allows us to carve-out from set $z$ the subset $y$ of all and only those elements that satisfy $\phi$.

Thus, we cannot use it to "create" sets *ex nihilo*, but we can only apply it to already existing set.

An example will be $\emptyset$, whose existence is asserted by the corresponding axiom: we have no issues in using it as $z$ in Axiom 3, exactly because $\emptyset \notin \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I still have trouble understanding why that is NOT a contradiction. If $y\in y $ is TRUE , then isn't $y\in z \, \wedge y\notin y$ FALSE?

Comment: @BijeshK.S - the issue is: given a set $z$, we have to find a "suitable" $y$ that satisfies the condition (we do not need that the condition must hold for every $y$). Thus, if we have that $z \notin z$, then we have that, choosing $z$ as $y$, $z \in z$ is FALSE and also $z \in z \land z \notin z$ is False. Thus, the bu-conditional is TRUE.